# Nested Formatting with For-Each display

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file with the following sample section:

```
<p>
                <hi rend="center"><hi rend="italic">Martinsburgh, July</hi> 24.</hi>
            </p>
            <p> We are informed, that one day last week, a <lb/>Mr. Barret, living near the
                South Branch, acci<lb break="no"/>dentally shot his wife;&#x2013;he was fixing a
                flint to <lb/>his gun, and incautiously dragging the trigger, not <lb/>knowing
                the gun was loaded, discharged the <lb/>whole contents into her body, and she
                died in a <lb/>few moments after&#x2013;the unfortunate woman had <lb/>a young
                child at her breast, but it providentially <lb/>received no injury. </p>
            <p> Alexander M'Gillivray advertises for a tutor, <lb/>willing to instruct Indian
                children in the rudiments of the English language; and the first prin<lb
                    break="no"/>ciples of <supplied reason="copy blur">arithmetic</supplied>. In
                the advertisement, this <lb/>chief <supplied reason="copy blur">??? ??? ???
                    ???</supplied> of the Creek nation. </p>
```

If I use this xsl file:

```
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="teiCorpus">
    <xsl:for-each select="TEI">
        <xsl:result-document method="text"
            href="Individual MD Entries\{teiHeader/fileDesc/sourceDesc/biblFull/publicationStmt/date/@when}_{teiHeader/fileDesc/sourceDesc/biblFull/titleStmt/title}_{teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/title}.md">
            <xsl:for-each select="text/body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='italic']">*<xsl:value-of select="."/>*</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:text>&#xd;&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get properly formatted paragraphs (no random line breaks) but the italics do not appear.  If I use this:

```
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="teiCorpus">
    <xsl:for-each select="TEI">
        <xsl:result-document method="text"
            href="Individual MD Entries\{teiHeader/fileDesc/sourceDesc/biblFull/publicationStmt/date/@when}_{teiHeader/fileDesc/sourceDesc/biblFull/titleStmt/title}_{teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/title}.md">
            <xsl:for-each select="text/body/p">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='italic']">*<xsl:value-of select="."/>*</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:text>&#xd;&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get properly italicised text, but I also get additional line breaks where they appear in the XML (for readability sake).  How can I get both?

**Update**

With the updated code (normalize-space) I get:

```
*Martinsburgh, July*24.

We are informed, that one day last week, aMr. Barret, living near the South Branch, accidentally shot his wife;–he was fixing a flint tohis gun, and incautiously dragging the trigger, notknowing the gun was loaded, discharged thewhole contents into her body, and she died in afew moments after–the unfortunate woman hada young child at her breast, but it providentiallyreceived no injury.

Alexander M'Gillivray advertises for a tutor,willing to instruct Indian children in the rudiments of the English language; and the first principles ofarithmetic. In the advertisement, thischief??? ??? ??? ???of the Creek nation.
```

I need:

```
*Martinsburgh, July* 24.

We are informed, that one day last week, a Mr. Barret, living near the South Branch, accidentally shot his wife;–he was fixing a flint to his gun, and incautiously dragging the trigger, not knowing the gun was loaded, discharged the whole contents into her body, and she died in a few moments after–the unfortunate woman had a young child at her breast, but it providentially received no injury.

Alexander M'Gillivray advertises for a tutor, willing to instruct Indian children in the rudiments of the English language; and the first principles of arithmetic. In the advertisement, this chief ??? ??? ??? ??? of the Creek nation.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace

```
<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='italic']">*<xsl:value-of select="."/>*</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:text>&#xd;&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='italic']">*<xsl:apply-templates/>*</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:text>&#xd;&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="lb[not(@break = 'no')]"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', ''), '\s+', ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As an alternative, one could first use the above `apply-templates` based approach, but store the result for each `p` in a variable and then use `normalize-space` on the variable as the final output.

Comment: That almost works, but now the line breaks are removed and I end up with one line running into another immediately without a space causing some words to be mashed up together.

Comment: This is a result of my <lb/> tags I think (which I need to include to indicate line breaks in other contexts

Comment: With that transformation to plain text, do you want to translate an `<lb/>` element into a newline character? Then add `<xsl:template match="lb"><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text></xsl:template>`. If that does not help then I think it is better you edit your question and show us the plain text you want to get for one of the sample paragraphs.

Comment: Have updated.  The problem is that moving into or out of any other element collapses the space, and I only want that to happen with <lb break="no"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

at the top level of your stylesheet.

Untested, because your input is not a well-formed XML.